# Trouble using swift 4's KVO "observe" instead of addObserver

Tags: swift4, key-value-observing, observers, keypaths

I'm having some trouble getting the new KVO syntax right.
According to the Apple documentation:

> Create an observer for the key path and call the
>   observe(_:options:changeHandler) method. For more information on key
>   paths, see Keys and Key Paths.

```
class MyObserver: NSObject {
    @objc var objectToObserve: MyObjectToObserve
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    init(object: MyObjectToObserve) {
        objectToObserve = object
        super.init()

        observation = observe(\.objectToObserve.myDate) { object, change in
            print("Observed a change to \(object.objectToObserve).myDate, updated to: \(object.objectToObserve.myDate)")
        }
    }
}

let observed = MyObjectToObserve()
let observer = MyObserver(object: observed)

observed.updateDate()
```

I'm initializing my observation like so:

```
self.observation = self.webView!.observe(\.webView.isLoading, changeHandler: { (webView, observedChange) in
    //code
})
```

but am getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Turns out the syntax needs to be like this, using the object Type rather than the object instance name:

```
self.observation = self.webView!.observe(\WKWebView.isLoading, changeHandler: { (webView, observedChange) in
    //code
})
```

Misread the documentation  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `\.` syntax the root element is the observed object so it's simply

```
self.observation = self.webView!.observe(\.isLoading, ...
```

---

The compiler treats your syntax as `webView.webView.isLoading` which is obviously not intended.

Comment: You should consider `self.observe(\.webView.isLoading, ...` instead. That is, if `self.webView` changes, you want KVO to automatically stop observing the old web view and start observing the `isLoading` property of the new one.